# Jackson JSON serialization in case of Delegation Pattern

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

In my model I use some sort of [delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). So, I have interface **A**, and two [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) classes **B** and **C** that implement the interface:

```java
interface A {
  int getCount()
  String getName()
}

class B implements A {
  final int count;
  final String name;

  B(int count, String name) {
    this.count = count;
    this.name = name;
  }

  int getCount() {
    return count;
  }
 
  String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}

class C implements A {
  final int value;
  final B delegate; 

  C(B delegate, int value) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.value = value;
  }

  B getDelegate() { return delegate; }

  int getValue() { return value; }

  int getCount() { return delegate.getCount(); }

  String getName() { return delegate.getName(); }
}
```

Then I want to serialize instance of **C** (say, `new C(new B(42, "Joe"), 7)`) as

```js
{
  "name": "Joe",
  "count": 42,
  "value": 7
}
```

and then I need to deserialize it back. I found a way to do the first half of the task, but I couldn't deserialize such JSON. Is it possible without custom deserializer?

Comment: How do you deserialize json? To class C?

Comment: @ekiryuhin yep, I serialize instance of C and then want to restore it back from the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement it with custom deserializer, but it may be fixed easier.
I think if you add setter methods for C class fields it will be works correctly.

Comment: It's a 'value object' - no setters allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```java
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
class C implements A {
  @JsonProperty
  final int value;

  @JsonUnwrapped
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
  final B delegate; 

  @ConstructorProperties({"name", "count", "value"});
  C(String name, int count, int value) {
    this.delegate = new B(count, name);
    this.value = value;   
  }

  C(B delegate, int value) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.value = value;
  }

  B getDelegate() { return delegate; }

  int getValue() { return value; }

  int getCount() { return delegate.getCount(); }

  String getName() { return delegate.getName(); }
}
```

There is some magic related to special constructor and access mode for unwrapped property due to Jackson limitations: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/106